# Microsoft Authenticator keeps asking for code from itself

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication

I am trying to add my Microsoft Work account to the Authenticator app, but it just keeps asking for a code from itself. I have clicked on the link which states 'I don't have the app available' and use 'another method', but it always just returns to asking for a code from the authenticator app. It's an endless loop. I can't log in on desktop or mobile and can't access my account to add/remove devices. I am completely stuck.